# Is there an easy bundle way to install Django, Python, Apache, MySQL/PostreSQL?

Tags: mysql, django, apache

I have a lot of websites, I usually like to setup an environment with PHP / MySQL / Apache.

However, now I'm starting to use Django, and it doesn't seem easy to setup, when I do it, I have to use sqlite and create a bunch of bat files for running the packaged development server, and install everything by itself. (I'm using windows on a lot of my servers).

But this is tedious, and the problems and steps become much more complicated if I want to use Apache instead of development server, and if I want to use MySQL instead of sqlite (or postreSQL). In fact, I don't even think you can easily get MySQL and Django working together, because mysql python module is required and the developer of that only uses Linux and has files set up for that purpose.

I think one of the reasons PHP/MySQL combo became so widespread is because of the availability of installers like Apache2triad, XAMPP, and WAMP. Do bundles like that exist yet for Django?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [bitnami-djangostack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack)